# mysql.connect() returns different type when used in with statement

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm using Flask with Flask-MySQL and was previously doing the following:

```
db = mysql.connect()
cursor = db.cursor()
#do database stuff
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

But I thought I'd make things a little cleaner and more idiomatic so I tried:

```
with mysql.connect() as db, db.cursor() as cursor:
    #do database stuff
```

It gives me the following error "AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'cursor'"

After a little investigation, when I do mysql.connect() on it's own it is returning a connection object but when I do it within a with statement... it's returning a cursor object!  So this works:

```
with mysql.connect() as cursor:
    #do database stuff
```

So what's going on here?  Why does the return type change when in a with statement?  I looked through the source code of Flask-MySQL but couldn't find anything...

Also, will this still work properly to close the db connection at the end of the with block?

Relevant version information:

- Python == 2.7.3
- Flask == 0.10.1
- Flask-MySQL == 1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression:

```
with X as Y:
    ....
```

does not mean that `Y` "is" `X`.  Rather, `X.__enter__()` is called and the result of that is then bound to `Y` for the body of the `with` statement.

At the end of the `with` body, or in the event of an exception, `X.__exit__(...)` is called to handle the success or failure.

In this case, the result of `mysql.connect()`, which is a connection, exposes a context manager that does the following:

- `__enter__` creates a cursor and begins a transaction;
- `__exit__` either commits or rollbacks the transaction as appropriate.

Comment: But when I check the source code for Flask-Mysql at https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/blob/master/flaskext/mysql.py there is no__enter__OR__exit__function in the class, only an__init__ function.

Comment: @jcmiller As I said, it is the **result** of `mysql.connect()` that exposes the context manager api.  In this case the result is the return value of `MySQLdb.connect` (see the code you linked) which is a `MySQLdb.Connection` ... that's the class which exposes the api.

Comment: Okay, thanks @donkopotamus that helped me wrap my head around it.